# Flutter - Future<void> can not be assigned to the parameter type Future<void> Function()

Tags: flutter, dart

I guess I am blind, but I can not see the problem...
Maybe someone can help me.

The Problem is in this line "onRefresh: updateData()" and the full message is "The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function()'."

```
late Future<DocumentSnapshot> dataFuture;

Future<void> updateData() async {
  setState(() {
    dataFuture = getData();
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: updateData(),
      ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're calling the function rather than providing it as an argument - should be just `updateData` rather than `updateData()`.

`onRefresh` expects a callback (a function) which would then be executed upon a refresh event. Here dart is telling you that you are providing the wrong argument type - a `Future` (the result of calling `updateData`) instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `async` and `await` then,

Replace,

```
onRefresh: updateData(),
```

To,

```
 onRefresh: () async {
   await updateData();
    },
```

Comment: Your solution also works, but I selected the solution of Tomer Ariel "updateData" instead of "updateData()". But also thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
onRefresh: () async {
          updateData();
          return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        }

void updateData() async {
  setState(() {
    dataFuture = getData();
  });
}
```